Why does the dimension of a subspace equal the dimension of the whole space minus the number of conditions on the set?
let's say we define a subspace $$ W = \{ p(x) \in R_3[x]\,\, | \,\, p(170) = 0\} $$
now it is very hard to determine this subspace's dimension via the condition and to solve all polynomials with degrees less than 4 that have 170 as a root, but there's somewhat of a theorem that says "the dimension of a subspace is the dimension of the father space minus the number of conditions", so here we can say that $$ Dim(W) = Dim(R_3[x]) - \#conditions = 4 - 1 = 3 $$
my question is why is that true in general? no need for a full proof I just need to know the intuition or a simple explanation to why is that true in general.

It's not true in general – the conditions have to satisfy an independence condition. E.g., the subspace of $(x,y,z)$ satisfying the three conditions $x+y+z=0$, $x+y-z=0$, and $x+y=0$ has dimension one, not zero.

I see, so in my example since it's the only condition, then it is in fact independent, therefore we can use this "rule".

Consider the linear transformation $T(p)=p(170)$ from $W$ to $\mathbb R$, obviously this is surjective, therefore by the dimension formula
$$\dim \ker T + \dim \text{range}(T) = \dim W$$
However, if there are a few more "conditions" say $p(a_1)=0, \cdots, p(a_m)=0$, you end up with a linear transformation $T(f)=(f(a_1), \cdots, f(a_m))$, the dimension formula still applies, but it won't be easy to know if $T$ surjective, hence you cannot just subtract the number of conditions, but only the number of independent conditions (equal to the dimension of the range of $T$).

thanks for the quick and easy to understand response.
